# Typescript - Why can a string type be overriden by a string literal

Tags: inheritance, typescript

Consider this little Typescript example:

```
interface Parent {
    name: string;
}

interface Child extends Parent {
    name: "Joe";
}
```

This works, but I don't quite understand, why.

My understanding of inheritance is, that ideally you should be able to say something like: "Child behaves the same way as Parent plus something", hence the word 'extends'. But in this case, Parent allows any string for name, whereas Child only allows for a particular string. So Child narrows the possibilities of Parent and you couldn't say, Child behaves the way Parent does. I am thinking about Liskovs substitution principle here.

So what is the rationale behind the way it works in Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For types, it has to do with assignability. The way types work is that the child type should be assignable to the parent type without an assertion.

In this case, the child is more specific than the parent so it's allowed—`"Joe"` is specific, `string` is general. It's assignable because `string` includes all possibilities of strings—that includes `"Joe"`.

**General includes specific, but specific does not include general**

For this reason, you can assign the child to the parent:

```
const child: Child = { name: "Joe" };
const parent: Parent = child; // ok, because name being "Joe" is assignable to string
```

But you can't assign the parent to the child:

```
const parent: Parent = { name: "Alex" };
const child: Child = parent; // not ok, because name being string might not be "Joe"
```

**Other Example**

It's the same reason why you can have a parent with an optional property and a child with a required property:

```
interface Parent {
    name?: string;
}

interface Child extends Parent {
    name: string;
}
```

**Mutability Danger**

When used appropriately, adding restrictions in this manner can be very useful. I do it occasionally.

It is dangerous when the properties are mutable though. If used incorrectly the following could happen:

```
const child: Child = { name: "Joe" };
const parent: Parent = child;
parent.name = "Alex";
console.log(child.name); // Alex
```

That might be why you're thinking about LSP. To avoid this danger, the object's properties can be marked as `readonly` and used in an immutable way.

Comment: But to my understanding, that is not, how inheritance usually works. child classes do not narrow down, they expand on their parents. They add stuff, don't they?

Comment: But good example you're giving there, I don't understand that either :D

Comment: @ghost23 normally implementations are more specific and base types are general. In this case it's pretty standard—you can assign `Child` to`Parent`, but you can't assign `Parent` to `Child`.

Comment: @ghost23 also, that's not the case. Think about child classes that implement a class with type parameters—ex `class MyClass extends MyBaseClass<string> {}`

Comment: I don't understand that last comment, @david. In this case, you are not extending MyBaseClass, but MyBaseClass<string>, so I see no violation.

Comment: The problem is, when we say, a child class is more "specific", what does that really mean? Usually we don't want to say, it does things differently than the parent, but rather, that the Child adds specific functionality, that the Parent does not have. That's different from altering already existing definitions of the Parent.

Comment: But I think, I begin to understand, what you're saying. The difference is, that we're talking about data types, not methods. I just looked, Java does not support defining properties in interfaces. So i guess, Microsoft had some thoughts on, why they did things differently for properties in interfaces and inheritance.

Comment: @ghost23 yes, think more about types and not functionality. From my understanding, LSP has more to do with functionality and probably shouldn't be thought about here. In this case, it's not altering the type of the parent, but narrowing the possibilities of data assignable to `Child`. Another narrowing we could do is to introduce a new required property.

Comment: @ghost23 I believe you may be confusing a pattern with possibilities. LSP as a paradigm that is encouraged, but does not reflect capabilities. (note: I am not saying that it is good or bad to add restrictions to children, I'm just making a distinction)